# minimize HTML repaint and reflow on webpage without overloading top with CSS or external CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, repaint, reflow

Here's an example of HTML code that would be perfect for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
A,BODY {background:#FF0;color:#000}
#BOX1 {width:100px;height:50px}
#BOX1 P{font-weight:bold}
#BOX2 {width:300px;height:60px}
#BOX2 P{font-size:200%}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="BOX1"><p>Test 1</p></div>
<div ID="BOX2"><p>Test 2</p></div>
<a href="whatever">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is my website uses adsense and the closer the adsense code is to the beginning of HTML the better because then ads load sooner.

If I were to modify my code to one of the following two fragments, which one will likely be less painful to the client (where the repainting and reflowing are at minimum)?

Code #1 (where individual style values are set in javascript):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#BOX1 {width:100px;height:50px}
#BOX2 {width:300px;height:60px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="BOX1"><p ID="BOX1P">Test 1</p></div>
<div ID="BOX2"><p ID="BOX2P">Test 2</p></div>
<a href="whatever">Click</a>
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor='#FF0';
document.getElementsByTagName('A')[0].style.backgroundColor='#FF0';
document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.color='#00F';
document.getElementsByTagName('A')[0].style.color='#00F';
document.getElementByID('BOX1P').style.fontWeight='bold';
document.getElementByID('BOX2P').style.fontSize='200%';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or Code #2 (appending new contents to the style tag):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#BOX1 {width:100px;height:50px}
#BOX2 {width:300px;height:60px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="BOX1"><p>Test 1</p></div>
<div ID="BOX2"><p>Test 2</p></div>
<a href="whatever">Click</a>
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('STYLE')[0].innerHTML+="A,BODY{background:#FF0;color:#000}#BOX1 P{font-weight:bold}#BOX2 P{font-size:200%}";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking for something that also works with older web browsers as well.
The reason why I left the measurement styles in the style tag is because I want to define the box sizes as the page loads so that text does not jump around after it loads.

Also, because the webpage size is small (under 20KB), I want to try to avoid using external stylesheets as it creates an additional request to the server.

Comment: _“and the closer the adsense code is to the beginning of HTML the better because then ads load sooner”_ – well then move it further up … no idea why you think this needs to involve that you violate your stylesheet as well? Also consider, that with your two JS approaches, those styles will be completely missing, if JS is not available. (Then there will be no ads either, and you sacrificed parts of your styling for nothing.)

Comment: If the site is under 20KB, then load times should not really be much of a worry to begin with. And if there is more than one page, you are even slowing things down, if you embed your styles inline (so they will have to be loaded again, with every new page), instead of having an external stylesheet that can be cached.

Comment: Adsense depends on JS to run properly and I can't just move the adsense code in the html `<head>` section. It has to be in the `<body>` section. It's the CSS styles at the beginning that push the ad code further down the HTML.

Comment: So you are willing to sacrifice the overall user experience of your site, just to bestow the gift of advertising upon visitors as soon as possible … now who wouldn’t appreciate that.

Comment: What you are wanting to do is actually slowing down painting cause javascript blocks loading of HTML when it hits that script tag. CSS will have those elements drawn faster and sooner than you can with script because the CSS object model is the first thing created after the DOM tree is made.